# mvc edditorfor disable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the code below to allow users name to be added to the from but i only want a admin user to be able to add user name manually. but a common user to only view the username which apperars fro them, how would i go about making the interlinked so that the data in the editttor can be viewd in the label

Current code to put in editor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

code changed

```
  @if (ViewBag.isAdmin == false)
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { id = "username" })
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            }
```

Rendered code

```
<label id="username" for="UserName">UserName</label>
<input id="UserName" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="UserName" data-val-required="Please enter a user name." data-val="true">
```

Comment: have you set ViewBag.isAdmin in action

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (ViewBag.isAdmin)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
}
else
{
    @Model.UserName
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
}
```

this is the easy way.